# Per page border-image in pure CSS

Tags: html, css, printing

I am making a small book (~20 pages). But the catch is that I want to show same content on a website. So, instead of making website and book in two dedicated formats (website in HTML, book in MS Word/Adobe pdf) I decided to go with one format: HTML + CSS. It makes all things far more easier. 
I want to place a border on each printed page. Like in old medieval like books. To do that I am using border-image rule, and it works fine.

```css
     article
    {
        border-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/4127/border.png) 27 round;
        -moz-border-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/4127/border.png) 27 round;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 9px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
        box-decoration-break: clone;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
        <body>
            <section>
                <article>
                    <h1>The chapter title</h1>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>...</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h1>The chapter title</h1>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>text</p>
                    <p>...</p>
                </article>
                <article>next chapter...</article>
            </section>
        </body>
    </html>
```

When using website version everything is ok. When trying to print that image border is broken. When you look at [box-decoration-break](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-break-3/#break-decoration) there
are two examples: for 'slice' value and for 'clone' value. I want my result to look like 'clone' but instead I am have 'slice' result.

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-break-3/#break-decoration

Comment: You will run into problems with this approach too. Simply because html is not at all well suited for print layouting. I would suggest you use a neutral base for that to write the content in (LaTeX or DocBook springs to mind here...) and then use a processor to generate the target formats from that.

Comment: It's a small project. I didn't want to use very complicated built process that will make all needed conversions. Thus, HTML seems like obvious choice. Apart from this issue I am pretty much happy on how HTML can be printed.

Comment: OK, your decision. Although converting LaTeX typically boils down to pressing a "convert" button... Anyways, you have to understand that html simply has no idea of what "a page" is. It is not a print oriented markup. There are no real means of control for pagination. So you have to use absolute measurements in your style rules and control that the content really does fit... At least css allows you to define separate styling rules for separate "media" targets. This is documented, it might help with the border issue. You probably want a div for each page with a border style rule...

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering I finally solved the issue. box-decoration-break is not supported by webkit based browsers (chrome, vivaldi). On other hand firefox seems to be working just perfectly.
Till this issue is fixed in webkit it's suggested to use firefox.

Answer (score 0):

i think if you check this checkbox in print window you can print the page correctly:
[The Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggLc6.png)

Comment: There is no correlation between those checkboxes and my missing borders.